# Is there a Jetpack Compose equivalent of A password field with the password visible to the user?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

- Product: Android App
- Programming language: kotlin

When using XML to create the UI. There is an option for a password field with the password visible to the user.
All the developer have to do is set the `inputType = TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`

In Jetpack Compose there is the option to create a textField(). Then pass in `visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation()` to make the typing turn into dots. However, it does not preview the letters for a few seconds before turning into dots like how it was with XML.

Was wondering if there is an equivalent jetpack compose function of a password field with the password visible to the user for a few seconds before it turns into a dot.

Thank you

Comment: `inputType = TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD` doesn't mean a preview of the latest char. The text is **visible** but the keyboard knows that it is a password in order to avoid, autocompletion, suggestions and other usage of the text.

Comment: _"However, it does not preview the letters for a few seconds before turning into dots like how it was with XML."_ Relevant issue still open in google's issue tracker -- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227770385

Answer (score 22):

The `inputType` configures the keyboard type that is shown, acceptable characters and appearance of the edit text.
With `1.0.0`  to have a Password field you can use a `TextField` with the [**`KeyboardType.Password`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/KeyboardType#ENUM_VALUE:Password):

`keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password)`

Check also [this ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173016926) for futher configuration.

To use a Password field with visualTransformation(mask character used instead of original text):

```
var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    value = password,
    onValueChange = { password = it },
    label = { Text("Enter password") },
    visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password)
)
```

To use a password field visible to the user, just remove the visualTransformation (and use the default `VisualTransformation.None`):

```
var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    value = password,
    onValueChange = { password = it },
    label = { Text("Enter password") },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password)
)
```

If you want to switch between the two options:

```
var passwordVisibility by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

TextField(
   //...
   keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
   visualTransformation = if (passwordVisibility) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
)
```

Comment: I have an issue with PasswordVisualTransformation(). When user types a number, after each number input keyboard changes to text mode. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

use three vars:

```
var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
var valueChanged by remember { mutableStateOf(false) } 
var transforms by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

then for TextField parameters use something like:

```
value = password,
visualTransformation =
                if (transforms) {
                    PasswordVisualTransformation('*')
                } else VisualTransformation.None,
onValueChange = { newValue ->
                if (...) {
                    password = newValue 
                    valueChanged = true
                    transforms = false
                }                    
            }.also {
                LaunchedEffect(it) {
                    if (valueChanged) {
                        delay(500)  // delay of half a second
                        transforms = true
                        valueChanged = false
                    }
                }
            }
```